# Is using 'to discriminate between' correct/idiomatic in the mentioned context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The company didn't tell us all that we needed to know about our rights. They told us
>   only some of the information we needed to know. They **discriminated
>   between** the facts of equally all of which we had the right to be aware. Or they **commited discrimination between** such facts.

By 'they discriminated between the facts ... ' I mean to say they told us only some but not the others, illegitimately and without any good reason and just because of their own interests. Is 'to discriminate between' idiomatically used here where it is about things and not persons?

This is one of the meanings of 'discriminate between' that is most close to what I have in mind.

> [discriminate between sb/sth (and sb/sth)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discriminate)
>
> The government was accused of putting up tariffs and discriminating
>   between domestic and foreign firms.

But the above is also about treating two legal entities differently, while in my example discrimination is not made between two persons or legal entities, but **between two *things* with regard to some persons**.

If my usage is not idiomatic, what else I can use instead? What I want is a verb meaning *to illegitimately treat two things differently concerning certain persons*.

Comment: The objects of *discriminate between* can be anything—people or things, tangible or not.

Comment: @JasonBassford Can you mention your source please ?

Comment: Any [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminate) will show all of the meanings of the word.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'discriminate' has taken on very heavy emotional significance in recent years. Not so long ago, I could boast of being a 'discriminating collector of antiques', meaning that I chose very carefully which antiques I wanted to collect.

Discrimination in the sense of deliberate and careful choice has come to mean choice influenced by improper, even illegal,  motives. So the act of discrimination becomes wrong in itself, leading to your phrase '...committed discrimination...'.

In your text you are indeed referring to improper motives, but what the company did was not discrimination, and the words you use are not right in that context. You mean the company 'suppressed information that we needed to know', or 'the company selectively told us only those facts that supported their case'.

Comment: so what about "the company was selective with information" or "... selective with facts"?

Comment: If the everything the company said was true but they did not tell you everything you needed to know then "... selective with [the ]facts..." is fine.

Comment: What about "selective *between* the facts ..."?

Comment: 'with' expresses the point completely. I don't think 'between' is actually wrong, but I don't think I have ever seen or heard it.